# What strategy will get the most distance for Home Run Contest?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I've tried using some characters with many-hit combos (Lil Mac, Yoshi) and I don't seem to be able to get more than 1500 ft. What strategy are the pros using to get those challenges beaten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ganondorf can hit it  over 7000ft, and doesn't require the Home Run Bat to do so:

- Start by doing 2 uncharged Smash attacks to the right.
- Immediately start doing tilt attacks to the left, 8 times. (Hold left and repeatedly tap Attack)
- Sandbag will land behind you. Still facing left, use Warlock Punch (Standard B) but immediately tap right. Ganondorf will turn whilst charging the punch.
- This special version of Warlock Punch does much more damage (2* or 1.5*, I forget), and will launch Sandbag clear of 7000ft (~1600m in the EU version). (If you jump, activate warlock punch, and turn, it does even more)

Comment: Interesting! I believe there's a challenge on board 3 that requires some absurd amount of total distance, so this would be a great way to put a significant dent in that.

Comment: This is the method I used to complete the challenge on board 3 (3298 ft). My method varied but changing direction during the warlock punch is very important.

Comment: I can agree with this, I get consecuitive 5000-6500 ft hits each time (unless I mess up in one of the areas).

Answer (score 2):

Just do as much damage as possible to the sandbag as possible before winding up with the baseball bat.

I myself have found stronger characters work better then fast characters. I got 2000+ ft. with King Dedede by hitting a spike ball at the sandbag repetitively until damage was about 80%-100% then  using the baseball bat to deliver the final blow. If your final percent after the final blow is over 119% then you are practically guaranteed to get over 2000 feet.

**Edit:**

Another important thing that I just realized is the position of the sand bag the further right on the platform it is the further the sand bag will go. I've seen the same damage count on the sandbag yield two very different distances based on where the sandbag was.

Answer (score 0):

As Ganondorf, without moving and timing it perfectly, do down smash, down smash, forward smash and bunch of forward tilts consecutively until you have to grab the bat then hit it perfectly at the tip. Got me 3,608 ft.

Comment: Do you happen to remember what percentage you got sandbag to?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is with *Ganondorf* but not those is smashes.

if you drop the bat and it hits the opponent he will pick it back up automatically. so I suggest trying that over and over and then smash. I have seen people get up to over **7000** using that strategy.

Comment: The opponent? Do you mean the sandbag?

Answer (score 0):

Ness. Get Sandbag on right, spam pk fire and swing bat at 2 seconds. Should net u 2 to 3.5k feet

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.0.8 comes the costs-money DLC character of Roy. Roy can get over 5,000ft easy peasy. Just do a bunch of f-smashes and f-tilts, and when the clock strikes 4, start charging Flare Blade (neutral special). Just when the clock hits zero, the move should detonate for ~50% damage and massive knockback.